# Drupal::entityQuery add CASE to have NULL values displayed last

Tags: entities, database

I want to sort some entities in ascending expiration date, but I want those without expiration date to be at the end. Is there a way to add a CASE expression like this to the Drupal::entityQuery?

```
    $entity_query = \Drupal::entityQuery($entity_type)
     ->accessCheck(FALSE)
     ->condition($some_condition)
     ->addExpression("CASE WHEN $table.$sorting_field IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
     ->sort($values)
```

Comment: No, not with `Drupal::entityQuery`. `addExpression` adds itself to the field list, e.g. something like `select <expression> from table`. You can not use addExpression to manipulate the `from`, `where` or `order by` clause. You have to go deeper and manually create a [database query](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/static-queries) for advanced SQL gimmicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a tag to the entity query, and then use [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/8.0.x) to manipulate it when it's been converted to a standard SQL query. e.g.

```
$entity_query = \Drupal::entityQuery($entity_type)
  ->addTag('advanced_sort')
  ->accessCheck(FALSE)
  ->condition($some_condition)
  ->sort($values);

...

function my_module_query_advanced_sort_alter(Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  // Add a field for the sort value.
  $alias = $query->addExpression(
    "CASE WHEN $table.$sorting_field IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END", 
    'foo_alias', 
    []
  );
  
  // Sort by it.
  $query->orderBy($alias);
}
```

The docs linked above have some examples on how to determine the alias for `$table`, you'll probably need to inspect the query a bit further to get a reliable value for `$sorting_field`.